# What are the canonical names for CMake steps?

Tags: cmake

I'm writing some documentation and wish to refer to the two main CMake steps using their canonical/usual/most-widely-understood names.

For the purposes of clarity, I'm interested in these two:

```
cmake -S . -B BUILD_DIR -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE      // the 'first' command
cmake --build BUILD_DIR                                 // the 'second' command
```

I've seen these called the *"Configure"* and *"Generate"* steps, respectively.  Equally, I could imagine calling them *"Parse"* and *"Build"* and so on.

I don't want to fall foul of this question being closed as "a matter of opinion", so to be clear: I'm asking if there is a standard terminology (explicit or de-facto) and what that is, or if no such standard exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man cmake` calls `cmake -S` step "Generate a Project Buildsystem", and `cmake --build` step - "Build a Project". I can't agree that `cmake --build` can be called "Generate".

Comment: The man page seems as authoritative a reference as any!  So "Generate" and "Build" seem standard.  I'll sit tight to see if anyone has a contrary opinion, and if not, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: The **Configure** and **Generate** steps are lumped into the "first" step: `cmake -S ...`